# lightning design system lookup UI not showing better, its show like two textbox type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup

`styleclass="slds-form-element slds-lookup"` this class not working lookup UI not looks good how to show lookup in lightning design system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this
this code paste in style tag

```
.lookupInput a{
                position: absolute;
                width: 33px !important; 
                margin-left: 5px;
                background-image: url(/img/setup/search-icon.png) !important;
                background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
                background-position: center !important;
              display: inline-flex !important;
            }
            .lookupInput input{
                width:91% !important;
            }
            .lookupInput a img{
                display:none !important;
            }
```

and style class on lookup field

```
styleClass="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input"
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by 'not looking good' and 'how to make look good' but please be aware that LDS provides multiple styling options as described [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/).

See the above link for details - some of the styling classes are shown here - http://grab.by/RHRy

Here are some styles for the lookup component using LDS

[image]

[image]

[image]